# Firebase multipath delete with orderByChild()

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Basically when a user deletes their account I am trying to clean up all the data in the RTDB.

This is no problem until I have to deal with a couple nodes where I need to use orderByChild to access them. Is this possible to do in an atomic / multipath update?

I have tried doing it inline like so:

```
      exports.removeUserFromDatabase = functions.auth.user()
          .onDelete(function(user, context) {
              // Get the uid of the deleted user.
              var uid = user.uid;

              const deleteUserData = {};
              deleteUserData[`users/${uid}`] = null;
              deleteUserData[`feed/${uid}`] = null;
              deleteUserData[`friends/${uid}`] = null;

                //THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO USE ORDERBYCHILD() TO ACCESS NODE
                deleteUserData[admin.database().ref('/friends').orderByChild(uid)] = null;

              deleteUserData[`profileThumbs/${uid}`] = null;
              deleteUserData[`hasUnreadMsg/${uid}`] = null;
              deleteUserData[`userChatRooms/${uid}`] = null;
              deleteUserData[`userLikedPosts/${uid}`] = null;
              deleteUserData[`userLikedStrains/${uid}`] = null;
              deleteUserData[`userLikedStrains/${uid}`] = null;

              admin.database().ref().update(deleteUserData)
      });
```

everything deletes except for where I am trying to use orderByChild(). There seems to be nothing (that I could find) regarding this.

I'd appreciate some guidance with this!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a node from the Firebase Realtime Database, you need to know its entire, exact path. There is no support for the concept of a *delete query*, where you pass a condition to the delete operation of the database.

If you want to delete all child nodes of `/friends` that have a certain value in a certain property, you will first need to execute the query and then delete all resulting child nodes:

```
admin.database().ref('/friends').orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid)
     .once("value").then((friendsSnapshot) => {
         friendsSnapshot.forEach((friendSnapshot) => {
             deleteUserData[`/friends/${friendSnapshot.key}`] = null;
         });
         admin.database().ref().update(deleteUserData)
     })
```